# Определить принадлежность ветки к каналу

Tags: python, discord, бот

Бот считает сообщения из каналов и записывает их в бд, но из веток этих каналов посчитать не может. Подскажите как определить что ветка принадлежит к каналу и посчитать из нее сообщение

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    cur.execute(f"SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid={message.author.id}")
    if cur.fetchone() is None:
        cur.execute(
            f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ({message.author.id}, '{message.author.name}', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)")
        base.commit()
    elif message.channel.id == channel:
        if len(message.content) > 5:
            for msg in cur.execute(f"SELECT channel FROM users WHERE userid={message.author.id}"):
                res = msg[0] + 1
                cur.execute(f"UPDATE users SET channel = {res} WHERE userid={message.author.id}")
                print(f'Юзер: {message.author.name} всего написал {res} сообщений в канал {message.channel.name} ')
        await bot.process_commands(message)
        base.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо
`elif message.channel.id == channel or hasattr(message.channel, 'parent_id') and message.channel.parent_id == channel:`